# how to translate x-axis plot code to ggplot code in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, x-axis

I'm having troubles using this idea with ggplot2

```
axis(1, at=1:6, lab=c("Art", "Basic", "Comp", "Day", "Est", "Fin"))
```

how can I do this with the ggplot2 package?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @math_ist. You would really need to show us the rest of your plotting code and your data to get a full answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would really need to show us the rest of your data and plotting code to get a full answer here, but an example would be:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = c(5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6, 
                     labels = c("Art", "Basic", "Comp", "Day", "Est", "Fin"))
```

[image]

Depending on what you're plotting, you may not even have to do this. For example, if your data was:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c("Art", "Basic", "Comp", "Day", "Est", "Fin"), 
                 y = c(5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1))
```

Then you could do, for example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_col()
```

[image]